# MySQL php creating a table containing foreign keys only (Error 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Im developing a database in php and I have the following two tables
Member Table:

```
$sql_query = "CREATE TABLE Member(
    ID              INT(8)          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Branch_ID       INT(8)          NOT NULL,
    Join_Date       DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Branch_ID) REFERENCES Office(ID) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB";
```

And a table Event:

```
$sql_query = "CREATE TABLE Event(
    Name        CHAR(30)        NOT NULL,
    Date        DATE            NOT NULL,
    Branch_ID   INT(8)          NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Name, Date),
    UNIQUE KEY (Event_Name, Event_Date),
    FOREIGN KEY (Branch_ID) REFERENCES Office(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB";
```

Finally, to keep track of which members attend which events, I have a table Attends_Event:

```
$sql_query = "CREATE TABLE Attends_Event(
    Event_Name  CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    Event_Date  DATE        NOT NULL,
    Attendee_ID INT(8)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Event_Name, Event_Date),
    INDEX Event_Name_Index (Event_Name),
    INDEX Event_Date_Index (Event_Date),
    FOREIGN KEY (Event_Name) REFERENCES Event(Name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Event_Date) REFERENCES Event(Date)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Attendee_ID)REFERENCES Member(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = INNODB";
```

But this table is never created(`Errno 150`). I've looked at other similar questions and seems like I have the correct code. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are trying to create two separate foreign keys on the event name and date, which cannot work due to relational integrity constraints put forth in the `Event` table (namely, that `Name` and `Date` are part of the primary key).  Instead, you want a single foreign key that includes *both* columns.  Try the following for `Attends_Event`:

```
CREATE TABLE Attends_Event(
    Event_Name  CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    Event_Date  DATE        NOT NULL,
    Attendee_ID INT(8)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Event_Name, Event_Date),
    INDEX Event_Name_Index (Event_Name),
    INDEX Event_Date_Index (Event_Date),
    FOREIGN KEY (Event_Name, Event_Date) REFERENCES Event(Name, Date)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Attendee_ID) REFERENCES Member(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE = INNODB
```

As an aside, the `UNIQUE KEY (Event_Name, Event_Date)` in the `Event` table will not execute since `Event_Name` and `Event_Date` are not columns in that table.  More important, however, is that this extra key is entirely redundant since `Name` and `Date` make up the primary key, which by definition is unique.

As another aside, I would recommend doing some query analysis before creating the two plain indexes in the `Attends_Event` table.  You probably actually want a composite index that covers `Event_Name` and `Event_Date`, but that may not actually be necessary since they are already part of the primary key.

And as a final aside, please check your modeling logic behind the `Attends_Event` table.  As it stands, you will only ever be able to assign one `Attendee_ID` to an event due to the primary key constraint.  If you're looking for a many-to-many relationship (which I believe you actually want), then include `Attendee_ID` into the primary key and you should be all set.

Comment: Good points. I'd also add that a surrogate PK on `Event` in the form of an auto-incrementing integer column might be a better idea, as that would give you shorter references in `Attends_Event`. That, however, would primarily be what I would do in SQL Server, I'm not sure if that point is of any relevance in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, a single foreign key rather than two was what was causing the problem.

Comment: Also, you are right about using Attendee_ID rather than Event name & date. That was a design defect on my part. The worst thing is, the logic was correct, I coded it wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Attendee_ID)REFERENCES Member(ID)
-- change to --
FOREIGN KEY (Attendee_ID) REFERENCES Member(ID)
```